# How do I make a video with a static image background in FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an image. I have a transparent FLV. I want to use the image as a background to the transparent FLV and have it outputted as FLV.

This command works but the video is one frame long:

```
ffmpeg -i background.png -f flv -vcodec flv -b 1500k -vf "movie=test_videos/alpha.flv [logo]; [in][logo] overlay=0:0 [out]" -s 800x464 -y output.flv
```

I have tried to use the -t and -vframes parameters to no avail.

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: There are some tricks that you can use to add an image on top of a video (watermark) but unfortunately I don't believe there exists anything in FFMpeg that allows you to do the reverse (chroma key/greenscreen/bluescreen).

Comment: Well, I already have a transparent video working with an image, so I hope to prove you wrong, @Chris Haas. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I apologize for my initial comment, my searching produced very little results initially.

Now looking at the [documentation](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#SEC152) I see in fact that you ***should*** be able to do that. I don't have time to test this but I would try making two passes. The first pass should turn your PNG into a movie with a transparent background that's the same duration as your other movie. Something like:

```
ffmpeg -loop_input -f image2 -i background.png -r 25 -vframes 250 -an -vcodec png test.mov
```

I chose PNG for the video codec because according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644684/turn-image-sequence-into-video-with-transparency) it supports transparency in MOV containers.

Then you should hopefully just be able to pipe that movie into your original command where you had your image.

Comment: Brilliant, Chris. The complete solution that got me what I wanted was this command:

ffmpeg -loop_input -f image2 -i background.png -r 25 -vframes 2500 -an -vcodec libx264 -b 1500k -vf "movie=test_videos/alpha.flv [logo]; [in][logo] overlay=0:0 [out]" -s 800x464 -y output.mov

Comment: Very great to hear! So basically it was just the `-loop_input` part that you needed to add to your original command, you didn't need to make two passes?

Comment: I started with an flv (flv supports transparency OOTB) and added it as an overlay over the static image (using loop_input and -vframes to make it longer than one frame), which seems a bit counter-intuitive. However, using this method, there was no need to make two passes. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: **Important TIP** to make the process **faster**: specify **4 or more THREADS** *(rule of thumb is 1 per CPU)* you put it first **`ffmpeg.exe -threads 4 -i back...`** . **Second tip**: if you are using `MP3` as the audio-track, and your target file extension is `.MP4` **specify `-acodec copy`** this way you'll save a lot of processing and you **can done within 10 seconds**. *You're welcome.*

Comment: -loop_input is deprecated. Here's an answer that works today: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14519/add-image-under-the-video-with-ffmepg

Answer (score 5):

The complete solution that got me what I wanted was this command:

```
ffmpeg -loop_input -f image2 -i background.png -r 25 -vframes 2500 -an -vcodec libx264 -b 1500k -vf "movie=test_videos/alpha.flv [logo]; [in][logo] overlay=0:0 [out]" -s 800x464 -y output.mov
```

Comment: that worked.
just one change is needed -loop_input is depricated so must use -loop 1